# C# - Executing a exe file which further invokes a msi file

Tags: c#, process, windows-installer, exe

I have a .exe file which checks the system architecture and based on the system architecture it calls the corresponding msi file.

I am trying to run this exe file from C# using the code below

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "my.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/quiet";
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "path//to//exe//directory";
Console.WriteLine(process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory);
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

The exe is getting invoked. i can see the application logs and there are no errors in the logs.

But the msi is not getting started or installed.
When I try to run the same exe file manually the msi is installed.

Note: There are other dependency files for this my.exe which are placed in the same directory.

Why am i not able to install the msi from C# program while i am able to do this manually.

I am running the VisualStudios in administrator mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this resolved after i added Thread.Sleep(). before "process.WaitForExit()"

Comment: Though this is working I am still not able to figure out why this is working. I understand the process was killed even before msi installation kicked off. But it would be great if i had more detailed expalnation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute .exe (and msi) as an administrator.

To ensure that, use:

```
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas"
```

Also, try it removing quiet arguments to see any possible errors.

Is "my.exe" installing your MSI if you call it, isn't it?

Comment: My.exe is supposed to install MSI.

Comment: But I am running visual Studio as an administrator

Comment: Can you share how you install msi? Can you try adding "l* C:\mylog.log"? msiexec /i <msifile> /l* C:\mylog.log      Can be somthing about the path and your "my.exe" not finding the msi file?

Comment: As I said it is the exe which actually installs the msi. I will need to talk to developer. Thank you.